# Pandas exact str matching function?

Tags: regex, pandas, exact-match

Does pandas have a built-in string matching function for exact matches and not regex? The code below for tropical_two has a slightly higher count. Documentation tells me it does a regex search.

```
tropical = reviews['description'].map(lambda x: "tropical" in x).sum()
print(tropical)
tropical_two = reviews['description'].str.count("tropical").sum()
print(tropical_two)
```

The first way is the answer key from Kaggle but something about it seems less readable and intuitive to me compared to a .str function because when I run this it returns True instead of 2 so I am a little confused about if the answer key method is actually counting all occurrences of "tropical" and not just the first.

```
def in_str(text):
    return "tropical" in text

in_str("tropical is tropical")
```

First 2 lines of dataframe:

```
 0  Italy   Aromas include tropical fruit, broom, brimston...   Vulkà Bianco    87  NaN Sicily & Sardinia   Etna    NaN Kerin O’Keefe   @kerinokeefe    Nicosia 2013 Vulkà Bianco (Etna)    White Blend Nicosia
    1   Portugal    This is ripe and fruity, a wine that is smooth...   Avidagos    87  15.0    Douro   NaN NaN Roger Voss  @vossroger  Quinta dos Avidagos 2011 Avidagos Red (Douro)   Portuguese Red  Quinta dos Avidagos
```

Notebook here, tropical code in cell #2
https://www.kaggle.com/mikexie0/exercise-summary-functions-and-maps

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Count the total number of times the word "tropical" appears in all reviews, or count the number of reviews that contain the word "tropical" at least once?

Comment: kindly add sample dataframe with expected output. from face value, it looks like `str.contains` covers this

Comment: I added a link to the notebook and moved this stuff to cell # 2. 

The prompt says "count how many times these two words show up in the description column" and I am unsure if the answer key code with the lambda only counts once per row. I am also unsure if the contains is counting words like 'tropically' that are not exact match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `str.count` with word boundary markers to match the exact search term:

```
tropical_two = reviews['description'].str.count(r'\btropical\b').sum()
print(tropical_two)
```

There may not be the need for a separate exact API, as `str.count` can be used for exact matches as well.

Comment: I tried this and it returns 0. I have it down as tropical 3 in cell #2 of the notebook: https://www.kaggle.com/mikexie0/exercise-summary-functions-and-maps

Comment: I have tested this code locally (with my own test data) and it seems to be working.  You should add sample data to your question.

Comment: Oh my bad, I used double quotes instead of single quotes. It works now. Double quotes gives 0 and single quotes gives a number slightly more than count or the lambda. Why does single vs double matter here?

Does the lambda only count once? If so then it's wrong.

Comment: I suggest double checking your data.  You could try dumping the description column to a text file, and then doing a regex search for `\btropical\b`.

Comment: I just made a test dataframe with "tropical tropical tropical" and "tropical tropical" as two row values and running the answer key lambda.sum() returns 2 not 5, your thing is correct, the answer key is wrong.